# How to Iterate column with multiple values using cypher?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

The code I tried was

```
    firstNode = graphDb.createNode();//creating nodes like this
    firstNode.setProperty( "person", "Andy " ); 
    Label myLabel = DynamicLabel.label("person");
    firstNode.addLabel(myLabel); ...

    relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.emails );// creating relationships like this
    relationship.setProperty( "relationship", "email " );....


    Transaction tx1 = graphDb.beginTx();
    try{
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);

        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]-(receiver) RETURN sender,  count(receiver)as count, collect(receiver) as receivers ORDER BY count DESC ");..
```

and the result I obtained was:

```
 sender                  | count | receivers                                                                 
Node[2]{person:"Chris"} | 3     | [Node[4]{person:"Elsa "},Node[0]{person:"Andy "},Node[1]{person:"Bobby"}] 
Node[4]{person:"Elsa "} | 3     | [Node[5]{person:"Frank"},Node[2]{person:"Chris"},Node[3]{person:"David"}]
Node[1]{person:"Bobby"} | 3     | [Node[2]{person:"Chris"},Node[3]{person:"David"},Node[0]{person:"Andy "}]
Node[5]{person:"Frank"} | 2     | [Node[3]{person:"David"},Node[4]{person:"Elsa "}
```

I want to iterate the receivers. so I tried the following :

```
for (Map<String,Object> row : result) {
               Node x = (Node)row.get("receivers");
               System.out.println(x);

               for (String prop : x.getPropertyKeys()) {
                  System.out.println(prop +": "+x.getProperty(prop));

               }
```

But it throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a simple thing.

```
try{
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);

        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]-(receiver) RETURN sender,  count(receiver)as count, collect(receiver.person) as receivers ORDER BY count DESC ");
        //ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]->(receiver)  WITH sender, collect(receiver.person) as receivers, RETURN {sender: sender.person,  receivers: receivers) ORDER BY size(receivers) DESC");
        //System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
        LinkedList list_prop = new LinkedList();

        for (Map<String,Object> row : result) {
            Node x = (Node)row.get("sender");
            Object y = row.get("receivers");
            System.out.println(y);  

            for (String prop_x : x.getPropertyKeys()) {
                System.out.println(prop_x +": "+x.getProperty(prop_x));

            }   

        }
        tx1.success();
    }
    finally {
        tx1.close();

    }
```

In the match query, I used "collect(receiver.person) as receivers" instead of  "collect(receiver) as receivers". It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your cypher query you collect the receiver.person property into an array called receivers. Receivers isn't a Node, its an array of properties. You can't cast that to strings. If you were looking to get the actual receiver nodes then you need to change your query statement to:

```
MATCH (sender:person)-[:emails]-(receiver) RETURN sender, count(receiver)as count, receiver as receivers ORDER BY count DESC
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the array of properties then you can do something like the code below:

```
Object receivers = row.get("receivers")
if(receivers instanceof String[]) {
  for(String receiver in receivers) {
    .. do something
  }
} else {
  // do something with receiver as a single string value
}
```

Clearly, you will need to change to type of receivers from String to the appropriate type if it isn't a String.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes. row.get("receivers") only throws error. But get("sender") works!!. I have edited the question.